# Bug with scatter chart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I implemented next [example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-series.html) from `dc.js` and found funny bug. When color repeats and the user does `mouseover` action on some lable with repeated color - chart show all data by current color, instead of showing  only by current label.

Chart:

[image: chart]

Bug with label `mouseover` :

[image]
[image]

I added some [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k8sjbbsn/1/) with this bug. How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest as a workaround, use different colors for all series? If you really want them the same color you could make the colors just slightly different, or even use different representations i.e. rgb vs hash vs color name haha yuck.

Comment: @Gordon Can you give me an advice how to set up different colors for all series? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug, a dig in the dc.js code confirm the problem. When drawing the legend items, are attached some callbacks on events. One important is the action done [on "mouseover" event](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/legend.js#L56) :

```
.on('mouseover', function (d) {
  _parent.legendHighlight(d);
})
```

Then, a look into the scatter.js code [let me confirm the bug](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/src/scatter-plot.js#L359) :

```
_chart.legendHighlight = function (d) {
    resizeSymbolsWhere(function (symbol) {
        return symbol.attr('fill') === d.color;
    }, _highlightedSize);
    _chart.chartBodyG().selectAll('.chart-body path.symbol').filter(function () {
        return d3.select(this).attr('fill') !== d.color;
    }).classed('fadeout', true);
};
```

We can see that highlighting is made by checking if the color of the item is the same than the color of the highlighted legend item. So, in your case, when colors are repeating, you highlight too many points.

So, you can probably register an issue [in the dc.js github](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues) because this is definitively a bug.

A simple fix is not possible in this case, to correctly highlight the good items, we miss identification of the items, today, in the generated html, nothing can identify or link the legend and the plots, one need to add something to link them (and that is easier to write here than to do it in the existing code ;) ).

Comment: Thanks Cédric, you are quite correct. [Here is the issue.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/727) Maybe the original author couldn't figure out a unique key to use here, but still it's just horrible.